# How to insert array elements in sql connecting with c++?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, sql-server, insert

After my connection to database, I surely insert elements to my table one by one, but I do not have any idea about inserting elements from an array, vector..etc to tables. 
Following query is that I tried, but no effects on table.

```
mysql_query(connection,"insert into mytable (id) values(arr[0])");
```

Comment: "insert into mytable (id) values(arr[0])" -> This is a constant string, nothing will be replace for arr[0] from your array/vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C/C++ don't interpolate values into a string as most scripting languages do. You'll have to use string operations to build the query string, e.g. (in pseudo-code):

```
str = "insert into mytable(id) values (" + arr[0] + ")";
```

instead. C has absolutely no way of knowing that `arr[0]` in that query string should be treated as an array reference, and not just plain text that happens to look like one. Hence having to build the string yourself.