# Binding an array to sql parameter

Tags: c++, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, dynamic-sql

Is there any way to bind an array, which are generated in c++, to a parameter in SQL-Statement. Something like this:

```
insert into Table1(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, datum) values (:1,:2,:3,:4)
```

in this example `:1`, `:2`, `:3`, `:4` are array parameter.

I know Table Variable is a very nice idea, but I would like to use another approache

Comment: Other classical methods are passing an XML as a parameter, or composing a string with the values, with a separator, like `1,2,3,4,5` and then splitting it SQL side

Comment: But I see it difficult that you are able to insert into a table 4 arrays... there isn't a column of type array in SQL Server

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898203/how-to-insert-array-elements-in-sql-connecting-with-c

Comment: Actually I dont need to inser an array in field in SQL server. I would like to add the content of each Array in a table.

Comment: @SantoshDhanawade thanks, but if the length of my array is 100, then I should run the INSERT statement 100 times. Somehow I would like to BULK INSERT of arrays

Comment: Use a prepared statement with a loop, or grab some library like POCO, QT, ...

Answer (score 1):

Using the suggestion given by Xantos, pass your array into a stored procedure in the form of a delimited string.  You can then use the delimited string in a table-valued function.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[String_To_Int_Table]
(
         @list NVARCHAR(1024)
       , @delimiter NCHAR(1) = ',' --Defaults to CSV
)
RETURNS
    @tableList TABLE(
       value INT
       )
AS

BEGIN
   DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(11)
   DECLARE @position INT

   SET @list = LTRIM(RTRIM(@list))+ ','
   SET @position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @list, 1)

   IF REPLACE(@list, @delimiter, '') <> ''
   BEGIN
          WHILE @position > 0
          BEGIN 
                 SET @value = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@list, @position - 1)));
                 INSERT INTO @tableList (value)
                 VALUES (cast(@value as int));
                 SET @list = RIGHT(@list, LEN(@list) - @position);
                 SET @position = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @list, 1);

          END
   END   
   RETURN
END
```

You can then use the table function to fill other tables...

```
-- check to see if contacts were included...
    if len(ltrim(rtrim(@Contacts)))> 0
    begin
        --create a temp table to hold the list of ids
        CREATE TABLE #TmpContacts (ID INT);

        -- use the table valued function to parse the ids into a table.
        INSERT INTO #TmpContacts(ID)
        SELECT Value FROM  dbo.String_to_int_table(@Contacts, ',');

        -- Select the @InterfaceID and the parsed ContactTypeIDs 
        -- for a bulk insert into the relational table...
        INSERT INTO [InterfaceContacts]
           ([InterfaceID]
           ,[ContactID]
           ,[Created]
           ,[CreatedBy])
        Select @InterfaceID, T.ID, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, sUser_sName()
        FROM #TmpContacts T;

        drop table #TmpContacts;
    end
```